# Removing link from :before items in menu

Tags: css

So I have the following code:

```
<style>
.menu {
        padding: 30px 50px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul a li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul a:not(:first-child):before {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  content: '\2605';
}
</style>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <a href="1"><li>LINK 1</li></a>
    <a href="2"><li>LINK 2</li></a>
    <a href="3"><li>LINK 3</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or if you prefer:
https://jsfiddle.net/f64z4tp8/1/

As you can see I have three links, and in between are an icon (star). However, I would like it so that the stars (before items) are not links. Can this be done ?

Comment: Your markup is invalid: only `<li>` can be the direct descendant of `<ul>`. Once you refactor your code, your issue will go away.

Comment: Hmmm, but I see this done all the times when people are making hamburger menus, i.e. <li> are enclosed by <a> tags. But this is maybe just because people are wrong as can be ?

Comment: They are wrong. Seeing it being done all the time does not mean it is correct (or semantically valid) ;) on an unrelated note, hamburger menus are bad: https://lmjabreu.com/post/why-and-how-to-avoid-hamburger-menus/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is incorrect: you cannot nest other elements except for `<li>` directly within `<ul>` (or `<ol>` too, for the sake of completeness). If you update your markup to reflect that changes, i.e.:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

and slightly modify your selectors by changing this:

```
.menu ul a:not(:first-child):before
```

...to this:

```
.menu ul li:not(:first-child):before
```

and you are good to go:

```css
.menu {
  padding: 30px 50px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu ul a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul li:not(:first-child):before {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  content: '\2605';
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change html code,  `a` element must be inside `li` element.

Like this:

```
<li><a href="1">LINK 1</a></li>
```

and also

`:before` for `li`

```css
 .menu {
        grid-area: menu;
        justify-self: right;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 30px 50px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'LemonReg', sans-serif;
}

.menu ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: $yellowish;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: $yellowish;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul li:not(:first-child):before {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  content: '\2605';
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="1">LINK 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2">LINK 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3">LINK 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you'll need to add the stars outside of the list links. You should also follow the [HTML specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) as much as possible, where  `<a>` are not valid `<ul>` child elements.

So the quickest solution would be something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/f64z4tp8/8/

**HTML**:

You can fix the HTML structure and use it according to the official specs by making the `<a>` elements children of the `<li>` items, like so:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="1">LINK 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="2">LINK 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="3">LINK 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

Since you changed the HTML structure, you'll also need to update the CSS selectors ensure you're still styling the stars and list items correctly, so change the rules that target `.menu a li` to just `.menu li` or just `.menu a`.

For example, on the selector where the star is added, change from `.menu ul a` to `.menu ul li`, ending up with something like this:

```
.menu ul li:not(:first-child):before {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  content: '\2605';
  color: $primaryRed;
}
```

---

**EXAMPLE SOLUTION**:

```css
.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  justify-self: right;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'LemonReg', sans-serif;
}

.menu ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: $yellowish;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: $yellowish;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul li:not(:first-child):before {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  content: '\2605';
  color: $primaryRed;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="1">LINK 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="2">LINK 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="3">LINK 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added `display:inline-block;` to the `.menu ul a:not(:first-child):before` css class. At this point the text-underline goes away and the stars become red.

This is because the CSS specs say:

> When specified on or propagated to an inline element, it affects all the boxes generated by that element, and is further propagated to any in-flow block-level boxes that split the inline (see section 9.2.1.1). […] For all other elements it is propagated to any in-flow children. Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu {
  padding: 30px 50px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul li:not(:first-child):before {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  content: '\2605';
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="1">LINK 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2">LINK 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3">LINK 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put as CSS selector:

```
.menu ul a:not(:first-child):before {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  content: '\2605';

  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

`pointer-events: none;` remove any pointer interaction with the `::before` element.

`text-decoration: none;` remove any default UI effect like underline.